# Conditional statement inside string inside php

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to evaluate date[3] to determine selected option.  All this is inside a php sql query.   I am not able to find out an easy way to get a selected for the value returned in date[3] in my $options string variable.

```
<?php  //sql statement
    foreach( $db->query($sql) as $data ) {

        $options = "<select type='text' name='pagephone'  select id='pagephone' >
       <option value=''></option>
       <option ". if ($data[3] == 'vtext.com' ){ echo 'selected' };. " value='vtext.com'>Verizon Wireless</option>
       <option ". if ($data[3] == 'vmobl.com' ){ echo 'selected' };. " value='vmobl.com'>Virgin Mobile</option>
       <option ". if ($data[3] == 'sms.alltelwireless.com' ){ echo 'selected' };. " value='sms.alltelwireless.com'>Alltel</option>";
       ?>
```

Comment: Use the `:?` operator to put a conditional in an expression.

Comment: Curious, if creating a whole `select` for each db return is intentional or not.

Comment: IcredibleHat1.   Since I could not figure it out I was going to use a if statement outside and hardcode the selected option.   Would just have many of them..... bad way to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to concatenate a value with `.`, so the value you use needs to be an expression that evaluates to a string. An `if` block is not such an expression, as you can see from the syntax error you get if you use the code from your question. You can use a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) expression instead, like this.

```
...<option ". ($data[3] == 'vtext.com') ? 'selected' : '' . " value='vtext.com'>
      Verizon Wireless</option>...
```

Personally, I would prefer to iterate an array of value/text pairs rather than hardcoding all the select options, like this:

```
$values = [
    'vtext.com' => 'Verizon Wireless',
    'vmobl.com' => 'Virgin Mobile',
    'sms.alltelwireless.com' => 'Alltel'
];

foreach( $db->query($sql) as $data ) {
    $options = "<select type='text' name='pagephone' id='pagephone'><option value=''></option>";

    foreach ($values as $value => $text) {
        $selected = ($data[3] == $value) ? 'selected' : '';
        $options .= "<option value='$value' $selected>$text</option>";
    }
    $options .= '</select>';
}
```

But that's just my opinion. Don't forget to close your `<select>`, though.